# Performance recovering data of big MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, innodb

I have a large table in MySQL (InnoDB) and I having some performance issues.

This is my structure:

```
id        UNSIGNED INT (PK)
tag_id    INTEGER (FK to tags)
value     FLOAT
datetime  DATETIME

UNIQUE INDEX (tag_id, value, datetime)
```

I'm inserting 3000 rows every 5 minutes. At this moment I have 12,7GB of information.

I want the user to see a chart with the next query or similar:

```
SELECT tags.name, value, datetime
FROM values
INNER JOIN tags ON tag_id = tags.id
WHERE 
    datetime BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-30'
    AND tag_id = 25
ORDER BY datetime ASC
```

Well, some time this query is fast (less than a second) and sometimes it takes more than a minute.

It's running on a Windows with the last version of MySQL Community.
The computer has 8GB of RAM and I changed this configuration:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G
innodb_log_file_size=48M
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it should be VERY fast, sicne you have a syntax error preventing it from running at all.. `between x and y tag_id` is not valid...

Comment: If `datetime` is a "DATETIME", not just a "DATE", then you are missing most of the last day of June.

Comment: The query is just an example, user has an input to select range. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance on that one `SELECT`:

```
INDEX(tag_id, datetime)  -- in this order
```

See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for further discussion.

Suggest

```
WHERE `datetime` >= '2015-01-01'
  AND `datetime`  < '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

You were missing all of Jan 1 and most of June 30.

Comment: I think is working! I executed the query using Heidi and this is the result:

/* Affected rows: 0  Filas encontradas (rows): 31.822  Advertencias: 0  Duración para 1 query: 0,078 sec. (+ 13,594 sec. network) */


So I understand the query is working fine but the problem is THE network (or maybe because of I/O)! I'm executing it locally.

Comment: If you are expecting to return lots of rows, and then processing them, consider doing some of the processing in the SELECT to avoid shoveling some much data?